# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: attribute_value.lastIndexOf is not a function

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I am running my cucumber test with selenium-webdriver.
When I run my feature the test fails with

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: attribute_value.lastIndexOf is not a function

```
[5] pry(#<Object>)> fill_in 'q', with: company_id
=> #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" 
path="/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/form/div/input[1]">
[6] pry(#<Object>)> click_on 'Search' 
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: 
attribute_value.lastIndexOf is not a function
(Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540469 
(1881fd7f8641508feb5166b7cae561d87723cfa8),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.0 x86_64)
from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@web-autotest/gems/selenium-webdriver- 
3.0.8/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok'


def self.assert_html
 # Search whole document instead of current_scope
  time = Benchmark.realtime do
    document = Capybara.page.document
    expect(document).not_to have_css('.pages500')

    log_entries = Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)
    log_entries.reject! { |e| %w(INFO WARNING).include? e.level }
    $world.puts "Browser log entries: #{log_entries.map(&:to_s)}" unless log_entries.empty?

    if Capybara.current_url.start_with? 'https'
      js = "tags_attrs = ["\
         "  ['script, source, audio, iframe', 'src'],"\
         "  ['object', 'data'],"\
         "  ['link', 'href'],"\
         "  ['form', 'action'],"\
         "  ['video', 'data-stream']"\
         "];"\
         "incorrect_urls = [];"\
         "for (i=0; i<tags_attrs.length; i++) {"\
         "  tags_attr = tags_attrs[i];"\
         "  elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tags_attr[0]);"\
         "  for (j=0; j<elements.length; j++) {"\
         "    element = elements[j];"\
         "    attribute_value = element[tags_attr[1]];"\
         "    if (attribute_value) {"\
         "      if (attribute_value.lastIndexOf('http://', 0) === 0) {"\
         "        incorrect_urls.push(attribute_value)"\
         "      }"\
         "    }"\
         "  }"\
         "}"\
         "return incorrect_urls;"
      incorrect_urls = page.execute_script(js)
      expect(incorrect_urls).to be_empty
    end
  end
end
```

Chrome version: Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Maybe anyone has any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: share your full code not only error.

Comment: `
str = find('.page-breadcrumb').text
     g = str.match(/(#)(\d+)/)
     company_id = g.captures.last 

    within '.tour-view-tabs' do
      click_on tab
    end

    fill_in "Username", with: email
    fill_in "Password", with: password
    find('.submitButton-customizable').click  

    visit site
    sleep 1
    fill_in 'q', with: company_id
    click_on 'Search' 

    click_on 'Add location'
    find('#id_input_address').set(address)
    sleep 1
    click_on "Save"
    sleep 1
    click_on "Save"
`

Comment: update it inside the question. so that we can find out where is 

attribute_value.lastIndexOf

Comment: I don't have any " attribute_value.lastIndexOf" at the my code. This error occured after I click_on "Search"

Comment: I found this code on the action.rb file. It's a "def self.assert_html" . This method used for click and visit methods

Comment: please update all those details in your question in a proper way. your code, error you are facing and in which case.

Answer (score 0):

The versions of `chromedriver` and `selenium-webdriver` you are using are massively out of date and not compatible with the version of Chrome you are using - update them.

Comment: I've updated chromedriver and selenium-webdriver and still get an error

'Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: attribute_value.lastIndexOf is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.80)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615355 (d5698f682d8b2742017df6c81e0bd8e6a3063189),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.0 x86_64)'

Comment: @SergeiLagun Now that you've added the code it's clear the issue is that `attribute_value = element[tags_attr[1]];` is returning something that isn't a string for at least one of the matching elements (and therefore doesn't support calling `lastIndexOf` on it).  This is because `element[tags_attr[1]]` is returning the matching property of the element which is not guaranteed to be a string.  One potential fix would be to change to `attribute_value = element.getAttribute(tags_attr[1]);` which will check the attribute (string) instead of property if that matches the requirements